# Windows Home permissions add SID, not username, for current user

Tags: windows, security, permissions

I've come across a peculiar issue for a user. They are using a home edition of windows, originally windows 8, just upgraded to windows 10 which I thought might fix it, but it hasn't.

Everything appears to be fine, they can use most programs (with 1 exception) with no problems. The exception is security, while it seems to work, something is missing: When adding their username to a folder permissions, the use only gets shown as the SID (not the username). I believe this is causing another program to fail as they can't determine the correct registry setting for where to place certain keys.

Is there anyway to fix this?

I've created another user on the machine, and that works as expected. (The erroring app then works, I am guessing because of this issue) I'd prefer to fix rather then completely restore the user though.

Comment: For the record, the OS always only stores SIDs in security descriptors; there's no way to store a user name and it wouldn't be secure to do so anyhow (since that user might get deleted or renamed, and then re-created, with the new user having access to the old user's stuff). It sounds more like you may have a problem with the SAM (Security Accounts Manager), as it should always be able to map a SID to a username for any existing user.

Comment: Thanks, yep realise they're all SIDs anyway, but you're right it's the mapping that's not working.  I think the SAM works fine, as the other user I've created maps to the username properly... but there's something messed up with the original user, meaning it breaks the SAM mapping.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution - switch to using local account rather then the Microsoft account.  Looks like maybe the registry became corrupted or something after switching to use the Microsoft account.

> In control panel/user accounts, "make changes to my account in pc
>   settings", and switch to using local.

This must reset the applicable registry errors, and allows the security accounts manager to map properly again.  (It can be switched back to MS login again after as well).